# SVG polygon unable to highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

I'm trying to highlight a specific polygon inside a SVG, by changing its stroke color.

Unfortunately, one side is completely covered by the second polygon's stroke.

I have tried to bring it to the front with z index, but no luck.

```
<button id="b1" type="button">1st</button>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1240 1000">
  <g>
    <polygon class="map__1" id="pol1" points="106.75,266 4,266 4,135 106.75,135 106.75,266" data-id="1">
    </polygon>
    <polygon class="map__2" points="178.25,168.655 106.75,240 106.75,135 145.75,135 178.25,168.655" data-id="2"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

js

```
let btn1 = document.getElementById("b1");
let pol1 = document.getElementById("pol1");

btn1.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    pol1.style.stroke = "#fc0303";
}
```

css

```
.map__1, .map__2 {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  fill: #6e6e6e;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfzbjxL3/

I also tried with the outline property, but it doesn't fits on other kind of polygons but squares.

Is there any way that I could manage to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: z-index won't work in SVG. Instead you can append the element in javascript using `appendChild` Please take a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to change the order of the polygons i.e using `appendChild`:

```
function myFunction() {
  pol1.style.stroke = "#fc0303";
  pol1.parentNode.appendChild(pol1);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0brakpc/)